# Putting a sensor_msgs/Image into a message, getting it back, and converting it for OpenCV?

Tags: ros, opencv, sensor-msgs, image, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just doing this wrong somehow.

I've got a Sensor_msgs/Image already. I want to put it into my message which has "Sensor_msgs/Image image" in it's definition.

Can I just do this:

```
msg.image = *imgPtr;
```

Or do I need to do some form of deep copy? The data types are a bit too complicated for me to figure out what's going on.

Later, in a service, I want to extract that image and convert it to a IplImage* for use with OpenCV. i'm trying this:

```
cv_img = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image, enc::BGR8);
IplImage img; 
img = cv_img->image;
```

And it seems to be working alright now, but it's hard to tell since i think that first bit is not working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9857/putting-a-sensor_msgs/image-into-a-message,-getting-it-back,-and-converting-it-for-opencv?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you take a look at the [cv_bridge tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-06**:
All messages should do a full copy on assignment.

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-05-02**:
Any idea on the first part - do i need to do a deep copy or something to put an image into the message file? I think the Image i'm sending is not working right now.